# Fixed posititon of inner element for outer element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image and a check image at right bottom of outer this image. I want, when i resize my windows, an checked image is still at right bottom of outer image. Using @media query is very complicated

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 list-parents-modal">
        <div class="parent-list-content-modal col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 alignCenter">
            <img ng-show="parent.check" class="img-check-modal" src="http://s22.postimg.org/mckimsgdp/tick_remove_parent.png">
            <img class="img-circle img-thumbnail img-thumbnail-modal" src="http://s23.postimg.org/yizg2hfgr/user_thumbnail_1.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.list-parents-modal {
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.img-check-modal {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: 105px;
    margin-top: 115px;
}
```

My fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhamMinhTan/0Ld93299/)

Comment: Do you want that image to be in same position or what ??

Comment: I want tick_remove_parent.png in same position. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe so?

```css
.list-parents-modal {
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.img-check-modal {
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 list-parents-modal">
        <div class="parent-list-content-modal col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 alignCenter">
            <img ng-show="parent.check" class="img-check-modal" src="http://s22.postimg.org/mckimsgdp/tick_remove_parent.png">
            <img class="img-circle img-thumbnail img-thumbnail-modal" src="http://s23.postimg.org/yizg2hfgr/user_thumbnail_1.jpg">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, you mentioned px instead of %. So try to use in `.img-check-modal` like

```
left:45%;
bottom:45%
```

instead of

```
margin-left:105px;
margin-top:115px;
```

Comment: I have tried this solution. But you know, in my fiddle. I have used circle image in Bootstrap framework, it will be responsive when i resize my window. So .img-check-modal not at same position. Anyway, your solution is right. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this the position will not be moved.

```
.img-check-modal {position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  right: 33%;
  bottom: 25%;
  margin-left: -6.6px;
  margin-top: -5px;}
```

Comment: It's run very well. Although, my result is not very good. But it's exactly what i want. Thank you very much. :)